# C style use of a modern C++ class

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I have a class like so:

**Snippet 1:**

```
struct B
{
    int member;
    // more complex members e.g. arrays of structs etc
};
```

This class is used in the code assuming it is a C style struct (e.g. used in **memcpy**, **memset** etc)

As part of good programming principles, I am contemplating modifying B like so:

**Snippet 2**

```
struct B 
{
    B() {}
    int member;
    // more complex members e.g. arrays of structs etc
};
```

Here is my understanding. Please correct if I got this wrong
a. Snippet 1 defines B which is a POD whereas Snippet 2 defines B which is not a POD, AND
b. In Snippet 2, B can still be legitimately used for C style uses such as memset and memcpy

1. std::is_pod : false
2. std::is_trivial : false
3. std::is_trivially_copyable : true
4. std::is_trivial : false

Extending, I would also follow the rule of Big 3 (or perhaps Big 5), I would add copy assignment as well as copy constructor.

Snippet 3:

```
struct B
{
    B() {}
    ~B(){}
    B& operator=(B &){ return *this; }
    B(B const &r){}
    int member;

    // more complex members e.g. arrays of structs etc
};
```

Here is my understanding. Please correct if I got this wrong
a. In Snippet 3, B can now no longer be legitimately used for C style uses such as memset and memcpy

1. std::is_pod : false
2. std::is_trivial : false
3. std::is_trivially_copyable : false
4. std::is_trivial : false

I need understanding on the effect of adding various members to B in Snippet 2 and Snippet 3 on C style uses of B.

Is the C Style use of a class really based on **is_trivially_copyable** or on **is_trivial** (which is more restrictive)?

Reading $3.9/2 indicates to me that in C++11 **"is_trivially_copyable"** is really the determining criteria. Some old C++ books (C++ in a nutshell e.g.) however indicate the criteria is about POD vs non POD and I understand that C++11 rules have changed since.

[Petes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984871/in-what-cases-do-we-need-to-know-if-a-class-is-trivial) response seems to indicate that trivial-ness is the necessary criteria

Comment: What does "$3.9/2" mean?

Comment: @Dennis Section 3.9, paragraph 2 of the ISO C++11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

If your struct only contains POD data members, and is not responsible for managing any resources, such as dynamically allocated memory, there's absolutely no reason to define the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operators. At most I'd add a constructor to initialize the data members. And with C++11, this can be done trivially using non-static data member initializers.

```
struct B
{
    int member = 0; // this will initialize the data member to 0
};
```

You could also add a constructor that takes an `int` and allows you to initialize `member` to any desired value. In that case

```
struct B
{
    int member;
    explicit B(int member = 0) : member(member) {}
};
```

Both of these changes will leave your class *trivially copyable* (9/6) and *standard layout* (9/7), which means you'll be able to use them with C-style functions.

---

From the discussion in the comments, it seems you're not necessarily interested in being able to initialize all data members, but still want to provide a default constructor.

```
struct B 
{
    B() {}
    int member;
    // more complex members e.g. arrays of structs etc
};
```

This is a bad idea because it doesn't add anything useful to the class, and makes it non-trivial because it now has a non-trivial default constructor. If you really want to define a default constructor, you should explicitly `default` it instead.

```
struct B 
{
    B() = default;
    int member;
    // more complex members e.g. arrays of structs etc
};
```

This leaves the class trivial, and standard layout, allowing you to use it with C style functions.

Comment: That was just a representative C style class. I will modify my post accordingly. Sorry about that

Comment: also the in class initializer makes the class a non POD. Are non PODs eligible for C style usage?

Comment: How much state is in general immaterial to the object semantics.

Comment: The addition of a user defined constructor makes a class non POD, once again

Comment: @user3701522 Yes, see the last sentence

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm not sure what that means

Comment: "If your class truly contains just a single int member there's absolutely no reason to define the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operators." — Whether there's zero, one, or two `int`s has no bearing on what other members might be useful.

Comment: @Praetorian: I agree, but as I mentioned in post, I would naturally extend this class for good OO design by adding copy constructor, assignment, destructor etc. That makes the class 'non trivially copyable', but 'standard layout'. Now does that permit C style usage?

Comment: @user3701522 I think the real answer to your question is that adding boilerplate never inherently improves design. Note that C++11 adds the alternative of `= default` definitions for all the special member functions, which allows explicitness but provides the same behavior as if you used the implicit definitions. You could then "define" all the special member functions and still have a POD, aggregate, whatever, class.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Fair enough, that wasn't the best choice of words in hindsight

Comment: @user3701522 What Potatoswatter said, there's no need to add a bunch of boilerplate to a class that only deals with POD types. The compiler generated copy constructor/assignment operator etc. are sufficient.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I can see your point. request you to crystallize it in a separate answer, please

Comment: @Praetorian: So, my understanding is to stick to Snippet 2 but not add copy constructor/copy assignment. But, that way the class still becomes POD. So back to my original question, is C style usage of POD classes fine?

Comment: It appears that standard_layout is a necessary condition for C style usage. But is it a sufficient condition as well?

Comment: @user3701522 That's the only one the standard calls out, so I'd say yes. Also note that with the `default`ed constructor your class is now a POD. That's pretty much the strongest guarantee you can get.

Comment: The Standard calls out for is_trivially_copyable in 3.9/2. Can you please point me to where it calls out is_standard_layout?

Comment: @user3701522 9/9 — Standard-layout classes are useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages.
Their layout is specified in 9.2.

Comment: You can `memcpy` precisely trivially copyable classes. Being standard layout or not has no bearing. You can do C-style inheritance (or in general C-style layout tricks) precisely with standard-layout classes. Being trivially copyable or not has no bearing.